# Как с помощью стилей сделать всплытие блока при скролле?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, анимация, прокрутка

Есть форма, которая всплывает вверх благодаря `css` анимации. Но, это работает, только если экран находится в пределах видимости.
Подскажите, а как сделать так, не используя сторонних бибдиотек, чтобы анимация срабатывала при скролле, если это не первый экран?

```css
.slideUp {
  animation-name: slideUp;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Connect with us</h2>
  <span></span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>

  <form name="sentMessage" class="slideUp" action="">
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required=""></p>
    <p><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required=""></p>
    <p><input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required=""></p>
    <p><textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: с помощью стилей не выйдет, нужен JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yTop - получаем положение блока на странице.
yBottom верхняя его часть + его высота = его нижняя часть (сразу за ней следует нужный нам блок, так как его нет мы и не можем получить его координаты)
scrollTop - прокрутка страницы + высота окна = нижняя часть окна
и когда нижняя часть окна больше чем нижняя часть блока за которым следует искомый элемент + якорь  = тру, творим колдунство.
Переводим якорь в фолс.
Работает адаптивно, так как все получаемые значения не абсолютны, а относительны (размеров окна и расположения в нем контента).

В проверке значение "-100" для того что бы анимация началась показываться заранее, до того как пользователь дошел до нижней части блока. Его можно изменить на ноль либо на положительные значения. (для положительного значения нужно больше контента, так как в данном случае блок является последним и прокрутка заканчивается, то проверка не выполниться и анимации не будет)

```js
var anchor = true;
$( document ).on( "scroll", function(){
  var yTop = $('.content').offset().top;
  var yBottom = yTop + $('.content').height();
  var scrollTop = $('body, html').scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  if( (scrollTop > (yBottom - 100)) && anchor ){
    $("#form").removeClass("hide").addClass( "slideUp" );
    anchor = false;
    console.log("scrolled");
  }
  
} );
```

```css
.slideUp {
  animation-name: slideUp;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  visibility: visible !important;
  display:block !important;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

#form.hide {
display:none;
visibility: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="height: 800px;">
  <h2>Connect with us</h2>
  <span></span>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>
  </div>

  <form name="sentMessage" class="hide" id="form" action="">
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required=""></p>
    <p><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required=""></p>
    <p><input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required=""></p>
    <p><textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: аа, я думал про якорь вы имелли ввиду немного другое - мол указать скрипты где начинается  искомый блок. У вас-то пример упрощенный (вы задали 800 пикселей по умолчанию), а самое сложное определить где блок начинается (блоки адаптивные) - получается только через подсчет высот каждого из блоков?

Comment: @Вася поправил ответ. Я так  понял ты говорил именно об этом.

Comment: @Вася если не до конца поймешь что происходит, добавь console.log(переменная) для каждой переменной и смотри как все работает. Думаю после этого все вопросы опадут.

Answer (score 2):

Как то так будет, если не хотите сторонней библиотеки. Я просто привел пример, дальше можете сами модифицировать `jquery`, определять высоту блоков до формы и по достижению высоты при скроле, делать `fire` своей формы.

```js
$( document ).on( "scroll", function(){
  
  if( $("#form").hasClass( "hide" ) ){
    $("#form").removeClass("hide").addClass( "slideUp" );
    console.log("scrolled");
  }
  
} );
```

```css
.slideUp {
  animation-name: slideUp;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  visibility: visible !important;
  display:block !important;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

#form.hide {
display:none;
visibility: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="height: 800px;">
  <h2>Connect with us</h2>
  <span></span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates voluptatem porro, dolorem numquam aperiam quas quae, soluta. Sapiente autem dicta impedit et quo harum, voluptatem, quibusdam dignissimos voluptate totam fugiat.</p>

  <form name="sentMessage" class="hide" id="form" action="">
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required=""></p>
    <p><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required=""></p>
    <p><input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required=""></p>
    <p><textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: да, но `jquery` это тоже библиотека/фреймворк

Comment: ну да, он в основном ведь используется. Я думал вы не хотите сторонние jquery библиотеки. Если так, то, можно на чистом JS, т.е. ,будет так `window.onscroll = function() { /*тут код*/ }` и не нужен тогда jquery вообще.

Comment: не совсем понимаю - вот так? просто в таком случае здесь при постоянном скроллинге срабатывает событие  ` window.onscroll = function() { 
  var slideUp = document.getElementById("hide");

  if (slideUp.classList.contains('slideUp')) {
     slideUp.style.display="block";
  }
 }`

Comment: ну тогда нужен якорь в коде anchor = true; в функции проверять его if(anchor){ код анимации; anchor = false; } и все, отработает один раз и больше беспокоить не будет.

Comment: @Dzianis Sadouski мысль понял, но как его в код поместить?

Comment: @Вася добавил ответ.